# Is there a name given to a group of symbols which are multiplied together?

Tags: terminology

If I have several terms (is that the right word?) multiplied together, is there a name for such a group?

E.g. $a \times b \times c + d \times e=z$

What would you call the groups $a \times b \times c$ and $d \times e$?

Comment: These are called *terms*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_(logic)#Elementary_mathematics

Comment: Terms, pretty much, or maybe *monomials* or *monomial expressions* if you want to be fancy about it.

Comment: Oh. So what I was calling a term is actually just a symbol or constant?